# WordPress mediaelement play button and volume control bar merged

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement

Recently I upgraded wordpress site from wordpress 4.1.5 to 4.2.2 after upgrade all my audio post are facing problem, the play/pause button and volume control bar are merged, the play button is hidden behind volume bar.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the Following codes in mediaelementplayer.min.css
.mejs-controls a.mejs-horizontal-volume-slider{height:26px;width:60px;position:relative;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle}

with following codes

.mejs-controls div.mejs-horizontal-volume-slider{height:26px;width:60px;position:relative;}

purge all the caches, it fixed the issue.

To prevent same problem from the future upgrades, I added the following code th custom_styles.css

.mejs-controls div.mejs-horizontal-volume-slider{height:26px;width:60px;position:relative;}

and don't care what is in mediaelementplayer.min.css

Thanks it is working now